# Ninject injection based on a route data value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, ninject

We've got an ASP.NET MVC application, that has a number of different areas. There are 2 areas that use the same C# classes from our service layer, but target different underlying data. I want these services to get different dependencies based on a value in the route data.

It's hard to explain, and I'm paraphrasing my class/area names. To illustrate:
[image: Call logic]

When the 'Code' is in the route data, I want to get different dependencies injected to when it is not present.

I understand there is the .When() method you can use to do conditional bindings, but I'm not sure how to get the route data from there. I could possibly also do it based on the area that it was called from, however thats not preferable in my instance (I think we may use the Code in that other area)

Is this possible?

Comment: This is a pretty well-put question. Does [the answer to what's pretty much a duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12676101/11635) provide any insight?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (it is for standard route configuration `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"`)

**Ninject configuration**

```
protected override Ninject.IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<IService>()
        .To<ServiceA>()
        .When(x => IsRouteValueDefined("id", null));
    kernel.Bind<IService>()
        .To<ServiceB>()
        .When(x => !IsRouteValueDefined("id",null));
    return kernel;
}
// just sample condition implementation
public static bool IsRouteValueDefined(string routeKey, string routeValue)
{
    var mvcHanlder = (MvcHandler)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
    var routeValues = mvcHanlder.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;
    var containsRouteKey = routeValues.ContainsKey(routeKey);
    if (routeValue == null)
        return containsRouteKey;
    return containsRouteKey && routeValues[routeKey].ToString() == routeValue;
}
```

it will use

- ServiceA for routes: /home/index/1, /home/index/2  etc.
- ServiceB for routes: / , /home/index  etc.

Comment: hmm this resulted in `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler'`

Comment: this was working for ASP MVC 2 - you can try to look through debugger to see, what type of `Handler` you have. Maybe it changed between versions of ASP MVC.

Comment: For newest MVC you should use `System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));` for getting route values.