# Can a Ninject binding be based on a URL/route value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I have a single controller that I want to use for CRUD operations on two different entities which implement the same interface. I'd like for Ninject to give it a different repository based on a query string value in the URL (or maybe a different URL, routed to the same controller). Is this possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's usually a design smell but you could define the binding like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IRepo>().ToMethod(ctx => 
{
    var a = HttpContext.Current.Request["a"];
    if (a == "b")
    {
        return new RepoA();
    }

    return new RepoB();
}).InRequestScope();
```

Comment: Kinda similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487200/ninject-injection-based-on-a-route-data-value ... Whadya say you answer that and we vtc this ? (or if you disagree, I'll remove the comment either)

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this is a smell?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, Getting A Specific value from a route

```
kernel.Bind<IRepo>().ToMethod(ctx => 
{
    var a = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["RouteDateValue"]
    if (a != null)
    {
        return new RepoA(a);
    }

    return new RepoB();
})
```