# MVC Conditional Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I am trying to figure out the best way to design an MVC4 application with DI via Ninject.

When the user comes to the system, they are presented with a login where they can select one of many databases. Each database is a separate catalog on a database server. What I need to do is inject a repository with the database connection details once the user is logged in. The type of repository does not change, just the connection details.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675977/can-a-ninject-binding-be-based-on-a-url-route-value/12676101#12676101) post which I could make work, but I am not sure if it is the best approach for my situation. What other options have people used with success?

Comment: Do you need to inject another repository, or do you just need to inject a different database connection / connection string?

Comment: @Steven, I need to inject the same type of repository but with the connection details of the relevant database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. As I am wishing to pass the connection string in the constructor for my concrete repository I can use the following Ninject WithConstructorArgument:

```
IBindingWithOrOnSyntax<T> WithConstructorArgument(string name, Func<Ninject.Activation.IContext, object> callback);
```

With this overload the callback is called every time an object is created. So my code looks like this and the MakeConnectionString method is called every time.

```
_Kernel = new StandardKernel();
_Kernel.Bind<ISomeItemRepository>().To<FakeSomeItemRepository>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", (c) =>
        {
            MakeConnectionString();
        });
```