# How to conditionally bind in ninject depending on the property value passed to controller/action in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

I have a interface with two implementation.

```
Bind<IWebLoginService>().To<WebUserLoginService>();
Bind<IWebLoginService>().To<WebAdminLoginService>();
```

I have a common login for both user and admin. For my system if some one logs in with `@mycompanyname.com` he is an admin and in that case I want to use the `WebAdminLoginService` service if not then the `WebUserLoginService`

**EDIT :** This email is present in the data posted to the controller `LoginAccountInfoModel`

Here is my login action

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(LoginAccountInfoModel accountInfoModel, string returnUrl)
{...}
```

Earlier I had two seperate views and action for admin and customer login, there i had implemented using `Named Binding`.

Pls advice.

Comment: You're going to have give more information.. Which property?  I don't see your IWebLoginService being used.. I assume it's in your constructor.  How would you expect the constructor of the controller to know about properties passed to the method, since the controller is instantiated before the model is bound?

Comment: IWebLoginService is injected in my controller's constructor. I want to be able to inject a different service depending on the value posted to the login method.

Comment: Yes, I got that... but I reiterate, how would you expect the constructor to know what is passed to the method when the controller is instantiated prior to the model being bound, ie the method parameters don't exist yet.

Comment: Oh. I got your point now. The controller will be instantiated before only even before the values are posted to the action method. How do u suggest I code for this ?

Comment: It's not pretty.  It's easy when you're using different controllers, since you can do simple conditional binding at that point.  But in the same controller, you would either have to use an ugly .ToMethod() binding in which you examine the HttpContext manually, or you would resolve the dependency in your method using kernel.Get().  Alternatively, you could inject an array of all your IWebLoginServices and select the correct authenticator from the array in the method.

Comment: See this for an example of the ToMethod: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675977/can-a-ninject-binding-be-based-on-a-url-route-value

Comment: Another option would be to inject a Factory object, that you would call in your method to create the correct service.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Will try something and get back to you here. Have tried something it worked posted it as an Update in my question. Your tots on this pls @ErikFunkenbusch

Comment: glad you found something that works.  I would mention that this is the Service locator pattern, and considered to be an anti-pattern.. But sometimes we have to make compromises.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch finally ended up injecting a factory object, added that as an answer below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another way I managed to do

**Step 1. Created a factory that would return me the correct service**

```
public interface ILoginServiceFactory
{
    IUserLoginService GetLoginService(string username);
}

public class UserLoginServiceFactory : ILoginServiceFactory
{
    private readonly IUserLoginService _userLoginService;
    private readonly IUserLoginService _adminLoginService;
    public UserLoginServiceFactory([Named("UserLogin")]IUserLoginService userLoginService, [Named("AdminLogin")]IUserLoginService adminLoginService)
    {
        _userLoginService = userLoginService;
        _adminLoginService = adminLoginService;
    }

    public IUserLoginService GetLoginService(string username)
    {
        if (username.Contains("@somecompanyname.com")) 
        {
            return _adminLoginService;
        }
        return _userLoginService;
    }
}
```

**Step 2 : Named ninject bindings

```
Bind<IUserLoginService>().To<WebUserLoginService>().Named("UserLogin");
Bind<IUserLoginService>().To<WebAdminLoginService>().Named("AdminLogin");
```

**Step 3 : Membership provider's bindings based on which service it's injected into**

```
Bind<MembershipProvider>().ToMethod(ctx => Membership.Provider);
Bind<MembershipProvider>().ToMethod(ctx => Membership.Providers["AdminSqlMembershipProvider"])
                          .WhenInjectedInto<WebAdminLoginService>();
```

**Step 4 : Ask the factory which service to use**

```
var webLoginService = _loginServiceFactory.GetLoginService(accountInfoModel.Email);
var signInInfo = webLoginService.SignIn(...)
```

Comment: Way to go..., this doesn't look very trivial but at least the Service Locator is gone.

Comment: I like your approach, much better in my opinion.  Glad my advice helped.

Answer (score 0):

After [speaking with  Erik Funkenbusch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286737/how-to-conditionally-bind-in-ninject-depending-on-the-property-value-passed-to-c#comment43041357_27286737) here is what I tried and this naive implementation worked for me.

When binding I have set the default binding to the WebUserLoginService

```
Bind<IWebLoginService>().To<WebUserLoginService>();
```

and in my controller I have this

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(LoginAccountInfoModel accountInfoModel, string returnUrl)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (accountInfoModel.Email.Contains("@somecompanydomain.com"))
            {
                _webLoginService = (IWebLoginService)System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(WebAdminLoginService));
            }
```