# How to read header in controller constructor

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to read header `Authorization` in my controller constructor? and how? and is this the best solution (reading header value in controller constructor) to achieve my goal ?

the following is my code of my classes that inherit an interface:

```
public interface IProvider
{
    string SendData(string data);
    //other methods
}

public class FirstProvider : IProvider
{
    private string _url;
    public FirstProvider(string url)
    {
        _url = url;
    }

    public string SendData(string data)
    {
        //send data to First provider website (_url)
        //return result
    }
}

public class SecondProvider : IProvider
{
    //some code
}
```

And the following API controller:

```
public class ProviderController : ApiController
{
    private IProvider _provider;

    public ProviderController()
    {
        //read authorization key from headers (How??)
        string authToken;

        //fetch from database/cache what provider to use based on the authorization key
        var provider = Providers.GetProvider(authToken);
        //Initialize _provider based on the database query result
        if (provider.Name == "a")
        {
            _provider = new FirstProvider(provider.Data);
        }
        else if (provider.Name == "b")
        {
            _provider = new SecondProvider(provider.Data);
        }
        //Other providers will be added in future
    }

    public ProviderController(IProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult SendData(string data)
    {
        _provider.SendData(data);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Are you trying to see if the caller is authorized? If so, then take a look at claims based authentication. There are a lot of options available in WebAPI to handle this.

Comment: Authorization is another step that I'm going forward with it,however,my problem isn't about authorization,it's about reading the authorization key in controller constructor (or anywhere else if this is not the best option) to fetch data from database (select Provider.Name from [ComplexQuery].....where authKey=[AuthKey from header]) that tells me which provider to use to initialize _provider and use it in other methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers`

However, you should use constructor injection (which you seem to already be going towards with the other constructor `public ProviderController(IProvider provider)`

You could use an IOC container to do conditional binding based on the request. See
[Ninject injection based on a route data value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487200/ninject-injection-based-on-a-route-data-value)

Comment: But is it OK (best practice wise) to call database/cache provider in `IsRouteValueDefined` ? I have to check in database which provider to use for that user (owner of that `Authorization` token)

Comment: Maybe use the factory pattern and have a class e.g. `ProviderFactory` have a method called `IProvider CreateProvider(object someObject)` to decide which `IProvider` to create.

Comment: @Padraic I have used to get the headers using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers`. But, it gives compile time error as `cannot resolve symbol 'Current'`

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu Have you referenced the `System.Web` assembly in your application?