# NULL HttpContext for batched OData requests in Web API - wrong design pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, ninject

I am trying to determine the correct method to inject a dependency into a controller where the concrete type to be injected is a variable based on a route data parameter.

So far I have the following set up which works perfectly for normal requests:

**Controller**

```
 public class OrdersController : ODataController
 {

    private IOrderService ErpService { get; }

    public OrdersController(IOrderService orderService)
    {
        ErpService = orderService;
    }

    [EnableQuery(PageSize = 100)]
    public IQueryable<OrderDto> Get(ODataQueryOptions<OrderDto> queryOptions)
    {
        return ErpService.Orders(queryOptions);
    }

    ...
    // Post
    // Patch/Put
    // Delete
}
```

With the following OData route config, I can specify the route template should include a 'company' parameter:

**Config**

```
config.MapODataServiceRoute( "ODataRoute", "data/{company}", model, new DefaultODataPathHandler(),
                conventions, new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
```

This allows me to have a static method to read the company ID from the URL:

```
public static string GetSalesCompanyFromRequest()
{
    var salesCompany = "";
    if (HttpContext.Current == null) return "";

    var routeData = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
    if (routeData.Values.ContainsKey("company"))
    {
        salesCompany = routeData.Values["company"].ToString();
    }

    return salesCompany;
}
```

Then, using Ninject, I can chose which concrete instance of IOrderService to use (simplified for brevity):

```
kernel.Bind<IOrderService>()
            .To<SageOrderService>()
            .When(ctx => GetSalesCompanyFromRequest() == "101").InRequestScope();

kernel.Bind<IOrderService>()
            .To<DynamicsAxOrderService>()
            .When(ctx => GetSalesCompanyFromRequest() == "222").InRequestScope();

kernel.Bind<IOrderService>()
            .To<SapOrderService>()
            .When(ctx => GetSalesCompanyFromRequest() == "333").InRequestScope();
```

**Connector Config**

```
Id          ErpType        ConnectionString
--------------------------------------------
111         Sage           "connectionstring1"
222         DynamicsAx     "connectionstring2"
333         SAP            "connectionstring3"
```

---

So here's how the following URLs get processed:

http://odata-demo/data/101/Orders 
Creates and injects a `SageOrderService` into `OrdersController`

http://odata-demo/data/**222**/Orders 
Creates and injects a `DynamicsAxOrderService` into `OrdersController`

The same logic applies to many different services, like:

- SageStockService/AxStockService
- SageBomService/AxBomService
- etc

***Note:***
I chose to put the company Id in the URL so I could configure a reverse proxy to forward requests to a local web server closer to the target database.

This all works perfectly until I try to use [OData Batching](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/01/introducing-batch-support-in-web-api-and-web-api-odata.aspx).
It seems then there is no `HttpContext.Current` (it is null) when I send a batched request.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12487200/2064829) asks something similar but does not account for OData batched requests.

[Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12676101/2064829) in this answer suggest injection by route data is code smell but does not elaborate.

So, the question is, how to I get `HttpContext.Current` for batched OData requests? Or Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the company is already in the route data, I could add an additional company parameter to every single action as follows to allow the company number to be passed in, then use a factory to get the right concrete type:

```
public class OrdersController : ODataController
{

    [EnableQuery(PageSize = 100)]
    public IQueryable<OrderDto> Get(ODataQueryOptions<OrderDto> queryOptions, string company)
    {

        var erpService = ErpServiceFactory.GetService(company);

        return erpService.Orders(queryOptions);
    }

    ...
    // Post
    // Patch/Put
    // Delete
}
```

This means that I would also have to initialise the OrderService within each action which smells a bit.

I suppose this could be less smelly if I used an ActionFilter to locate and pass in the correct concrete type to the action:

```
public class RequiresOrderServiceAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        string salesCompany = "";
        var data = actionContext.Request.GetRouteData();

        if (data.Values.ContainsKey("company"))
        {
            salesCompany = data.Values["company"].ToString();

            var orderService = ErpServiceFactory.GetService(company);

            actionContext.ActionArguments.Add("erpService", orderService);
        }
    }
}

public class OrdersController : ODataController
{

    [EnableQuery(PageSize = 100)]
    public IQueryable<OrderDto> Get(ODataQueryOptions<OrderDto> queryOptions, IOrderService erpService)
    {
        return erpService.Orders(queryOptions);
    }

    ...
    // Post
    // Patch/Put
    // Delete
}
```

Thoughts?