# How to use route values in controller dependency injection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

Our company has three major programs and the majority of our applications are multi-tenant with the data segregated by program. Our web applications use the first route segment to indicate the program, so our default MVC route is

```
{program}/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

I have a rule that any class that has a dependency on the program only accepts the program info in its constructor. In MVC or Web API controllers, I want to create any dependencies in their constructors (manually or using a DI framework) which means that I need to access route values in controller constructors.

Initially this was straightforward because I could access route data using the static property

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData
```

Now it's more complex because I am supporting MVC and Web API, sometimes in the same project, both with a mix of defined and attribute routing. I've also started looking at bootstrapping Web API using OWIN and I haven't discovered a way to access route data in a controller constructor in that case.

All of which leads me to believe that I'm doing it wrong. What is the best way to do constructor dependency injection when the dependencies require a value from the request route?

---

Clarification: My application consists of MVC and API controllers. I have dependencies that require a value from the route. Overriding the Initialize method is the "right" way to access route data early in a controller's lifetime and it allows me to create my dependencies manually.

I now want to use constructor DI using Ninject or another DI framework but I am not sure how to access route data in a constructor. System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData works in 2 of 3 use cases (standard MVC and API) but feels wrong. It does not work in the 3rd use case which is Web API using OWIN startup.

What is the best way to do constructor DI when dependencies require a route value?

Comment: are the controllers re-used across multiple programs? Or are they also segregated via program?

Comment: if they're reused, then {program} is basically just another id, and I think you're trying to use it too soon. If you just grab it off the action method and pass it into your service layer, along with the id, then you can filter on both...... if they aren't reused, just create a separate query service per program and use DI as you normally would to pass it in

Comment: They are re-used. Functional differences are very minor, the main difference is that either a separate connection string is needed where multi-tenancy uses separate databases, or the ProgramId must be included in queries where all data is housed in a single database.

Comment: oh hm.....I see the problem now

Comment: "use DI as you normally would to pass it in" -- I still need to get the program from the route data. Where I'm doing DI manually I can just override Initialize and access route data (though I'd prefer to do it in the ctor). Where I'm using a DI container I can do it using System.Web but not with OWIN. Plus it feels dirty.

Comment: This question is very similar but doesn't cover OWIN: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487200/ninject-injection-based-on-a-route-data-value. Of course I found it 5 min. after posting this question despite a lot of searching.

Comment: yeah I didn't realize the connection strings changed, that changes things, i'm looking into it

Comment: so you're good then?

Comment: if not, it appears that you can change DI mappings via different routes for at least the ninject ioc container. You could just pull out a different web config connection string and pass it into your DAL in the constructor, but that also depends on if you're using code first or not. Pretty sure database first uses convention to grab the connection string . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675977/can-a-ninject-binding-be-based-on-a-url-route-value

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm currently doing. What I'm doing and the previous answers rely on getting the current context from System.Web. I think that's a code smell and it doesn't work with OWIN. My question asks what is the best way to use route values in constructor DI. Thanks for the conversation, I'll add a bounty when I can tomorrow.